# Even with complete and readable statements, an error occurs: SQL Error [900] [42000]: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables created in my Oracle database: the table 'responsible' (which has the id and description of the responsible) and the table 'ident' (which has id's of three types of expenses).

Below, I am trying to create a script in which:

- Add values to the columns of the 'responsible';
- create a 'type_responsible' table, and insert values into it;
- create a relationship table called 'responsible_by_type', which, using the data from the table 'responsible', 'ident' and 'responsible_type' establishes one relationship between them.
- These changes in data type to primary key or foreign key are attempts to get the bank to recognize the fields as relatable.

I get the error: 'SQL Error [900] [42000]: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement'. Even if I execute one instruction at a time, which makes no sense.

I really don't know where my mistake is. Since I can't run the script, I can't know if the script allows me to reach my goal. Could someone help me?

```
<--Table RESPONSIBLE-->

INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE(RESPONSIBLE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_DESC) VALUES (1, 'payer1');
INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE(RESPONSIBLE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_DESC) VALUES (2, 'payer2');

ALTER TABLE RESPONSIBLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RESPONSIBLE_ID PRIMARY KEY (RESPONSIBLE_ID);
ALTER TABLE RESPONSIBLE ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_RESPONSIBLE_DESC UNIQUE (RESPONSIBLE_DESC);


<--Table IDENT-->

<--OPTION ONE-->
ALTER TABLE IDENT ADD CONSTRAINT pk_RESPONSIBLES_TYPE_IDS primary key(RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID, RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID, RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID);

<--OPTION TWO-->
ALTER TABLE IDENT ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID FOREIGN KEY (RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID);
ALTER TABLE IDENT ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID FOREIGN KEY (RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID);
ALTER TABLE IDENT ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID FOREIGN KEY (RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID);


<--Table RESPONSIBLE_TYPE-->
CREATE TABLE RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID NUMBER(10), RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC) VALUES (1, 'Assets');
INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC) VALUES (2, 'Expenses');
INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC) VALUES (3, 'Debts');

ALTER TABLE RESPONSIBLE_TYPE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID PRIMARY KEY (RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID);


<--Table RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE-->
CREATE TABLE RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, RESPONSIBLE_DESC VARCHAR(100), RESPONSIBLE_TYPE VARCHAR(100), 
CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_ID) REFERENCES RESPONSIBLE(RESPONSIBLE_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID) REFERENCES IDENT(RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID) REFERENCES IDENT(RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID) REFERENCES IDENT(RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE) REFERENCES RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_DESC) REFERENCES RESPONSIBLE(RESPONSIBLE_DESC);
```

In the first steps it was running. From the moment I created the table 'responsible_by_type' and started changing the data types of the other tables, I couldn't do anything anymore.
Now, even when I execute a simple insert instruction, I get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: How and where (which client) are you running this? And do you really have comments in `<-- ... -->`? That might be what it's complaining about. Or it might not allow multiple statements in one go - again, depends on the client.

Comment: I'm guessing from "SQL Error [900] [42000]" you're running this in some sort of Java framework? If so, make sure you do not include the trailing semicolons in your SQL statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works from Oracle SQL Developer

```sql
--  ******************* Existing Table RESPONSIBLE - you don't need to create it ***************************
--CREATE TABLE RESPONSIBLE 
--  (
--      RESPONSIBLE_ID   NUMBER(10), 
--      RESPONSIBLE_DESC VARCHAR2(100)
--  );
--  -------------- Alter table --------------------
ALTER TABLE RESPONSIBLE ADD CONSTRAINT pk_responsible_id PRIMARY KEY (RESPONSIBLE_ID);
ALTER TABLE RESPONSIBLE ADD CONSTRAINT unique_responsible_desc UNIQUE (RESPONSIBLE_DESC);
--  ---------- I n s e r t s ----------------
INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE(RESPONSIBLE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_DESC) VALUES (1, 'payer1');
INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE(RESPONSIBLE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_DESC) VALUES (2, 'payer2');

--  ******************* Existing Table IDENT - you don't need to create it  ***************************
-- CREATE TABLE IDENT 
--  (
--      RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID NUMBER, 
--      RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID NUMBER, 
--      RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID  NUMBER
--  );
--  -------------- Alter table --------------------
ALTER TABLE IDENT ADD CONSTRAINT pk_responsibles_type_ids 
    PRIMARY KEY(RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID, RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID, RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID);


--  *************** New Table RESPONSIBLE_TYPE ***************************
CREATE TABLE RESPONSIBLE_TYPE
    (
        RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID NUMBER(10), 
        RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC VARCHAR(100),
        CONSTRAINT pk_responsible_type_id PRIMARY KEY (RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID)
        -- option 2 -- PK(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC)
    );
--  ---------- I n s e r t s ----------------
INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC) VALUES (1, 'Assets');
INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC) VALUES (2, 'Expenses');
INSERT INTO RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC) VALUES (3, 'Debts');

--  *************** New Table RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE ***************************   
CREATE TABLE RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE
    (
        RESPONSIBLE_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
        RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
        RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
        RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
        RESPONSIBLE_DESC VARCHAR(100), 
        RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID NUMBER(10), 
        -- NOTE *** FK Constraints References PKs in referenced tables *** ----------
        CONSTRAINT fk_resp_by_type_resp
            FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_ID) REFERENCES RESPONSIBLE(RESPONSIBLE_ID),
            
        CONSTRAINT fk_resp_by_type_idnt
            FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID, RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID, RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID) 
            REFERENCES IDENT(RESPONSIBLE_EXPENSES_ID, RESPONSIBLE_ASSETS_ID, RESPONSIBLE_DEBTS_ID),

        CONSTRAINT fk_resp_by_type_resptype
            FOREIGN KEY(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID)
        -- option 2 -- FK(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC) references RESPONSIBLE_TYPE(RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_ID, RESPONSIBLE_TYPE_DESC) 
    );  
-- R e s u l t
table RESPONSIBLE created.      
table RESPONSIBLE altered.
table RESPONSIBLE altered.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
table IDENT created.
table IDENT altered.
table RESPONSIBLE_TYPE created.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
table RESPONSIBLE_BY_TYPE created
```